# Extending hline within a colorbox environment

Tags: colorbox, hline

I am trying to extend the hlines of the following table such that they span the entire width of the colorbox, but can't seem to figure out how. The current Latex code looks like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{newtxmath}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\definecolor{sky-blue}{RGB}{223,230,243}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\vspace{0.5cm}
\setlength\fboxsep{0ex}
\centering
\colorbox{sky-blue}{
\begin{tabular}{p{3.3cm}cp{3cm}}
\hline
\textbf{Distribution}&\textbf{Densityfunction}&\textbf{Parameters}\\\hline
\\[-1.5em]
Normal&$\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp{\left(-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}\right)^2\right)}$&$\mu\in\mathbb{R},\;\sigma>0$\\
\\[-1.5em]
\hline
\\[-1.5em]
Logistic&$\exp{\left(\frac{-(x-\mu)}{\sigma}\right)}\bigg/\left(\sigma\left(1+\exp{\left(\frac{-(x-\mu)}{2\sigma}\right)}\right)^2\right)$&$\mu\in\mathbb{R},\;\sigma>0$\\
\\[-1.5em]
\hline
\\[-1.5em]
Gen.extremevalue&$\exp{\left(-\left(1-c\left(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}\right)\right)^{1/c}\right)\left(1-c\left(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}\right)\right)^{1/c-1}}$&$\mu\in\mathbb{R},\;c,\sigma>0$\\
\\[-1.5em]
\hline
\end{tabular}
}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Which gives the following output:

[image]

As you can see, the hlines don't entirely span the colorbox. I have tried adjusting the margins of the colorbox through the fboxsep command, but this does not seem to do the trick. Any ideas?

Comment: [Welcome to TEX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/82917) Please provide a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/82917) starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}` instead of code snippets. This makes our lives easier and increases the chance of people helping you.

Comment: Thank you campa! I have updated the code to a full working example. Hope it helps.

Comment: The newline after `\colorbox{sky-blue}{` is interpreted as a space. Replace with `\colorbox{sky-blue}{%` and at the end `\end{tabular}%`. With the newline commented out there is no space so the lines cover the full box.

Comment: That works! Thank you @Marijn :)